# Unable to Migrate Using TContextService

Tags: entity-framework-core, migration, dbcontext

```
public static void AddECommerceDbContext(this IServiceCollection services, string connectionString)
{
    services.AddDbContext<IECommerceDbContext, ECommerceDbContext>(
    optionsAction: options =>
    {
        options.UseSqlServer
        (
            connectionString,
            seqOptions =>
            {
                seqOptions.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(ECommerceDbContext).Assembly.FullName!);
            }
        );
    },
    contextLifetime: ServiceLifetime.Scoped,
    optionsLifetime: ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
}
```

**First Command:**

I used the following command to migrate but encountered an **ERROR**:

> Add-Migration init -Context IECommerceDbContext -Project
> ECommerce.Persistence

ERROR:

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
No DbContext named 'IECommerceDbContext' was found.
```

**Second Command (*this one Working*):**

> Add-Migration init -Context ECommerceDbContext -Project
> ECommerce.Persistence

**Expectations:**

I registered the *ECommerceDbContext* to be used through *IECommerceDbContext*.

However, I am curious about how the migration is working here when I specifically specified to access *ECommerceDbContext*'s instance through *IECommerceDbContext*.

Comment: what is the exact error message you are getting

Comment: @YoussefSell,
ERROR: The type or namespace name IECommerceDbContext could not be found. Note that, if I use ECommerceDbContext instead of IECommerceDbContext when running the migration, the migration gets created, even though I haven't registered ECommerceDbContext in the Dependency Injection (DI) container.